# Replace numbers in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array populated with zeros and ones and after the array is created I need to replace some of the zeros with ones. Here is my code for the array:

```
grid = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(4,4)) 
np.random.shuffle(grid)
```

I tried:

```
grid[grid == 0] = np.random.binomial(1, 0.9, size = None)
```

and:

```
grid[grid == 0] = np.random.randint(0, 2)
```

But then all the zeros are replaced with 1 or not replaced at all. Is there a way to replace only some of the zeros?

Comment: Yes, you need a way to identify just the *elements/items* that you want to replace - `grid == 0` specifies **all** zeroes.  There are a few ways that you can index an ndarray. - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
grid += np.random.binomial(1, 0.9, size=grid.shape) * (grid == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a single draw, draw multiple times

```
grid = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(4,4))
np.random.shuffle(grid)

grid[grid==0] = np.random.binomial(1, 0.5, size = grid[grid==0].shape[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You better try again.

for me the shuffle method works.

```
np.random.shuffle(grid)
```

although seems to work only after applying it twice....